# How to create custom messagebox?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

My `MessageBox` doesn't give value in real time.
I'm trying to create a custom messagebox that gives values according to which button was pressed.

My code is working but it's not giving me the value in real time.
Is there any way I can get the value in real time?
Where I'm not doing good, help me...I see a lot of people there don't answer me and tell me the reason of it, too.

Basically I want to value like real messagebox of python tkinter. Like we create its object and it has the value according to which button was pressed - something like that. I hope you understand.

```
from tkinter import *

class MessageBox(object):

    def __init__(self,title='Mess', msg='', b1='OK', b2='',b3='',b4=''):

    # Required Data of Init Function
        self.title = title      # Is title of titlebar
        self.msg = msg          # Is message to display
        self.b1 = b1            # Button 1 (outputs '1')
        self.b2 = b2            # Button 2 (outputs '2')
        self.b3 = b3            # Button 3 (outputs '3')
        self.b4 = b4            # Button 4 (outputs '4')
        self.choice = ''        # it will be the return of messagebox according to button press

    # Just the colors for my messagebox

        self.tabcolor = 'red' # Button color for Active State
        self.bgcolor = 'blue'    # Button color for Non-Active State
        self.bgcolor2 = 'yellow' # Background color of Dialogue
        self.textcolor = 'Green' # Text color for Dialogue

    # Creating Dialogue for messagebox
        self.root = Toplevel()
    
    # Removing titlebar from the Dialogue
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)

    # Setting Geometry
        self.root.geometry("300x120+100+100")
    
    # Setting Background color of Dialogue
        self.root.config(bg=self.bgcolor2)

    # Creating Label For message
        self.msg = Label(self.root,text=msg,
                        font=("Helvetica",9),
                        bg=self.bgcolor2,
                        fg=self.textcolor,
                        #anchor='nw'
                        )
        self.msg.place(x=10,y=28,height=60,width=280)

    # Creating TitleBar
        self.titlebar = Label(self.root,text=self.title,
                             bg=self.bgcolor2,
                             fg=self.textcolor,
                             bd=0,
                             font=("Helvetica",10,'bold')
                             )
        self.titlebar.place(x=100,y=5)
    
        # Creating Close Button
        self.CloseBtn = Button(self.root,
                                text='x',
                                font=("Helvetica",12),
                                command = lambda : self.closed(),
                                bd=0,
                                activebackground='red',
                                activeforeground='white',
                                background=self.bgcolor2,
                                foreground=self.textcolor)
        self.CloseBtn.place(x=260,y=0,width=40)
 
        # Changing Close Button Color on Mouseover
        self.CloseBtn.bind("<Enter>", lambda e,: self.CloseBtn.config(bg='red',fg='white'))
        self.CloseBtn.bind("<Leave>", lambda e,: self.CloseBtn.config(bg=self.bgcolor2,fg=self.textcolor))

    # Creating B1 
        self.B1 = Button(self.root,text=self.b1,command=self.click1,
                        bd=0,
                        font=("Helvetica",10),
                        bg=self.bgcolor,
                        fg='white',
                        activebackground=self.tabcolor,
                        activeforeground=self.textcolor)
        self.B1.place(x=225,y=90,height=25,width=60)
    
    # Getting place_info of B1
        self.B1.info = self.B1.place_info()
    
    # Creating B2
        if not b2=="":
            self.B2 = Button(self.root,text=self.b2,command=self.click2,
                            bd=0,
                            font=("Helvetica",10),
                            bg=self.bgcolor,
                            fg='white',
                            activebackground=self.tabcolor,
                            activeforeground=self.textcolor)
            self.B2.place(x=int(self.B1.info['x'])-(70*1),
                          y=int(self.B1.info['y']),
                          height=int(self.B1.info['height']),
                          width=int(self.B1.info['width'])
                          )
    # Creating B3
        if not b3=='':
            self.B3 = Button(self.root,text=self.b3,command=self.click3,
                            bd=0,
                            font=("Helvetica",10),
                            bg=self.bgcolor,
                            fg='white',
                            activebackground=self.tabcolor,
                            activeforeground=self.textcolor)
            self.B3.place(x=int(self.B1.info['x'])-(70*2),
                          y=int(self.B1.info['y']),
                          height=int(self.B1.info['height']),
                          width=int(self.B1.info['width'])
                          )
    # Creating B4
        if not b4=='':
            self.B4 = Button(self.root,text=self.b4,command=self.click4,
                            bd=0,
                            font=("Helvetica",10),
                            bg=self.bgcolor,
                            fg='white',
                            activebackground=self.tabcolor,
                            activeforeground=self.textcolor)
            self.B4.place(x=int(self.B1.info['x'])-(70*3),
                          y=int(self.B1.info['y']),
                          height=int(self.B1.info['height']),
                          width=int(self.B1.info['width'])
                          )

    # Making MessageBox Visible
        self.root.mainloop()

    # Function on Closeing MessageBox
    def closed(self):
        self.root.destroy() # Destroying Dialogue
        self.choice='closed'#Assigning Value
        
    # Function on pressing B1
    def click1(self):
        self.root.destroy() # Destroying Dialogue
        self.choice='1'     # Assigning Value

    # Function on pressing B2
    def click2(self):
        self.root.destroy() # Destroying Dialogue
        self.choice='2'     # Assigning Value

    # Function on pressing B3
    def click3(self):
        self.root.destroy() #Destroying Dialogue
        self.choice='3'     # Assigning Value

    # Function on pressing B4
    def click4(self):
        self.root.destroy() #Destroying Dialogue
        self.choice='4'     #Assigning Value

root = Tk()

def func():
    a = MessageBox(msg='Hello I m your multiline message',
                    title='Hello World',
                    b1='Button 1',
                    b2='Button 2',
                    )
    print(a.choice)

Button(root,text='Click Me',command=lambda : func()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'd try assigning a textvariable to the Messagebox that points to a StringVar. You can then utilize the .set() and .get() methods of the StringVar to update the text.

Comment: I didn't get it bro.... We use the functions to change the text of widgets or inside them..

Comment: No, I **don't** understand: "Like we create its object and it has the value according to which button was pressed". Create and change *what* object and value? When a button is clicked in your `MessageBox`, it destroys itself.

Comment: I want to use if statement on {a} after making the object.

Comment: You can do that if you do what Bryan Oakley suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be calling `mainloop` inside the class. As a general rule of thumb you should only ever call `mainloop()` once the the life of the program. You already call it in the main logic after creating the root window so you shouldn't call it again.

Instead, you can use `wait_window` to wait until the window is destroyed before returning:

```
# Making MessageBox Visible
self.root.wait_window()
```